# How to load .obj file from URL at runtime for android sceneform sdk

Tags: android, .obj, sceneform, mtl-file

I have a lot of .obj file and .mtl files stored remotely.

Now, i wish to load those files in the sceneform sdk at runtime because the files are dynamically generated and i can't possibly load millions of them all bundled with the app.

Is it possible to do that? Can the models loaded be then feed into the augmented face functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the tool https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/obj2gltf to convert it to glb on a server and then load the glb asset through RenderableSource.Builder()